# 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll

Tags: c#, ado.net, sql-server-ce, sql-server-ce-4

I'm using **SQL CE 4.0** and am running into a **StackOverflowException** when the **SqlCeDataAdapter** attempts to **Fill** the **DataTable**.

The code is pretty standard :

```cs
using (var cmd = new SqlCeCommand(sql, conn, tran))
using (var dt = new DataTable())
{
    using (var da = new SqlCeDataAdapter(cmd))
        da.Fill(dt);

    IList<DataRow> rows = dt.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().ToList();
    foreach (DataRow row in rows)
    {
        // Processing ...
    }
}
```

The `sql` string is in the form of :

```sql
SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE Id IN ( ... )
```

The total character count is `1,068,369` due to the column value list being filled with `27,393` values of type `uniqueidentifier`.

Executing that query should return results with 1-for-1 rows from the database. Instead, the **StackOverflowException** occurs. I feel as though I am running up against some sort of **SQL CE 4.0** limitation.

---

I've read [Understanding Databases (SQL Server Compact) > Database Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172451.aspx) and under the **Queries** section it reads :

> Characters in an SQL statement    |    Unlimited

`1,068,369` characters is less than `unlimited`; **PASS**.

---

I've read [DataTable Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx) and under the **Remarks** section it reads :

> The maximum number of rows that a DataTable can store is **16,777,216**

`27,393` rows is less than `16,777,216`; **PASS**.

---

Is there something else that I'm missing?

Comment: `foreach (DataRow row in dt,rows)` would do the same without a new list ... just curious

Comment: @Plutonix - I don't disagree; I inherited the code. That said, we bomb before that line. We are bombing on `da.Fill(dt);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The code is pretty standard" (!) - but the SQL statement is not!
It is obviously an engine bug/doc error, but do not expect a fix from Microsoft.
You will have to change the code to work with smaller batches of ids, resulting in a statement that is not 1 MB in size with 27.000 values.

Comment: I knew it had to be something with the column values list. I had this same thought last nite and I ended up batching 5000 values at a time and it works fine. Thanks for the confirmation of it being an engine/doc bug.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like your sql server runs out of temp space when running this query. You can test this by changing the query to return only one row and not using the IN statement. if this works then as mentioned before check or ask your DBA to check that the system has been allocated the resources to run the query and build the result set before returning it to your application. PS. IF multiple persons use this application at the same time then this problem will scale horribly.

Comment: The overarching process is a disconnected field app that syncs back to the server on demand. It syncs every table in the SQL CE db with its respective match back on the server. I have verified that other tables sync just fine. This particular field person hadn't synced in over a week which is typically supposed to be done nightly ( probably due to a reason such as this ). I'm not going to say it's not a resource thing, but I have 16GB RAM, am running an Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790 CPU @ 3.60 GHz, and am able to repro the issue.

Comment: What does the mentioned sql server connection connect to. Your local machine or the server?

Comment: This specific part of the code is connecting with a `SqlCeConnection`, so it would be the local sdf database file.